# Import Error : Can not import get_close_matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I run The Following code expected to match a word from JSON  data file but I got an error ...
This Is My Code

```
import json
from difflib import get_close_matches 
data = json.load(open("data.json"))
# print(data.keys())

def translate(w):
    if w in data:
        return data[w]
    else:
        return "Word Does't Exist !!! "

word =input("Enter World:-").lower().strip()
print(translate(word)
```

And Here Is the Error:-

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_close_matches' from 'difflib' (d:\Python_Books\Programe\project\difflib.py)
```

Comment: Change your script's name to something else than `difflib.py`